# How to move the files from one directory to another in c?

Tags: c, file-io

I am creating a project on moving a directory files by creating sub-folders according to their particular type in `c`. I have made up to creating directories with the help of `POSIX` library `dirent.h` for the files having different extension present in the home directory but I don't know how to cut a file from home directory and paste in its particular sub-folder. So please guide me about how can I `cut` and `paste` a file from one directory to another in `c`.

Comment: Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx  ,hope this will solve it

Comment: Note that there is no standard way of delaing with directories in C, so you need system-specific libraries (such as POSIX, which you've mentioned).  Some systems may not even have a concept of directories.

Comment: "cut" and "paste" are user interface metaphors that have little to do with actual file system operations.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rename(DestinationFilepath, SourceFilepath);`

For more info check man page http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename

For two different system use cURL library:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL

Code in C:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DESTINATION_FOLDER "/home/second/"
#define SOURCE_FOLDER "/home/first/" 

void printdir()
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat statbuf;
    struct tm      *tm;

    char src_folder[1024];
    char dest_folder[1024];

    if ((dp = opendir(SOURCE_FOLDER)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"cannot open directory: %s\n", SOURCE_FOLDER);
        return;
    }
    chdir(SOURCE_FOLDER);
    while ((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        lstat(entry->d_name, &statbuf);

        if (!S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
            sprintf(src_folder, "%s%s", SOURCE_FOLDER, entry->d_name); 
            sprintf(dest_folder, "%s%s", DESTINATION_FOLDER, entry->d_name); 
            printf("%s----------------%s\n", entry->d_name, dest_folder);
            rename(src_folder, dest_folder);
        }
    }
    chdir("..");
    closedir(dp);
}

int main()
{
    while (1) {
        printdir();
    }
    rename("aaa.txt", "/home/second/bbb.txt");
    printf("done.\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: This would only work if source and destination are located on the same partition.

Comment: @someone please give me some reference of lstat() function.

Comment: @OldSchool: type [`man lstat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html) into a terminal to see the manual page.