# How to cut and paste or move files between two directories?

Tags: c, file-io

How we can move a file from one directory or cut and paste to another directory in c?i am using `POSIX` c.i know the algo and using `dirent.h` header but to move a file i am uable.

Comment: what platform it is ?

Comment: Duplicate (same user): [How to move the files from one directory to another in c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856040/how-to-move-the-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-c)

Comment: take a look at `cp` command source code.
http://coreutils.sourcearchive.com/documentation/7.4/cp_8c-source.html

Comment: Downvoters please care to comment. OP has not shared any effort which he has made to the question. Do we need to give the working code for this question. i dont understand why my answer was downvoted?(Because I have done the best what is required for this question)

Answer (score 1):

`C` doesn't support the concept of a filesystem, you have to find a library for that and that library will likely be some platform-specific library .

In case of a GNU/Linux based OS `libc` offers [some interesting posix extensions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-System-Interface.html).